# How to improve this code that only uses the write function from libc

Tags: c

I had to write a function that takes an int number as an arguments and prints it to the terminal, but there's a twist: i can only use the function write from glibc. I am a beginner, how can I improve this piece of code without going into complexity?
btw the title is so long because i couldn't post with a shorter one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int power(int num, int exp)
{
    int n = num;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < exp-1; ++i)
    {
        n = n*num;
    }
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
    return n;
}

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    int n = nb;
    int i = 0;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        ++i;
        n = n/10;
    }
    for (i = i-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        ft_putchar((nb/power(10, i))%10 + '0');
    }





}

main()
{

    ft_putnbr(1234);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first candidate for improvements is the `power()` function.

1. If the `exp` parameter is 0, your function should return 1 immediately, without unnecessary calculations, loops etc. It can be achieved by moving the `if` instruction to the beginning of the function. Or, you can eliminate this checking using `1` as the start value for `n` and extending the loop, like below:

```
int power(int num, int exp)
{
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
    {
        n = n * num;
    }
    return n;
}
```

2. The next thing is that you are using only powers of `10`, so passing this by parameter is not necessary. Simply rename your function to `power10()` and pass the exponent only:

```
int power10(int exp)
{
    int n = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
    {
        n = n * 10;
    }
    return n;
}

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    ....

    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        ft_putchar((nb / power10(i)) % 10 + '0');
    }
}
```

3. Or, if you want to have more "generic" `power()` fuction, you should add the checking for `0` number (in this case `0` value should be returned regardless to exponent), and for negative exponents (`0` value should be returned too):

```
int power(int num, int exp)
{
    if ((num == 0) || (exp < 0))
        return 0;

    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
    {
        n = n * num;
    }
    return n;
}
```

4. Finally, if you want to speed-up your code, you should rethink replacing the call for calculating the power of `10` with simple static array of powers like below:

```
static int power10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000,
                        10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};
....

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    ....

    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        ft_putchar((nb / power10[i]) % 10 + '0');
    }
}
```